# JQuery not working in bootstrap remote Modal

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

bootstrap 3.Modal work in the remote mode. using input floating label using jquery is not working in remote Modal

index.html

```
<div class="loginButton col-md-auto col-lg-auto hidden-sm hidden-xs" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login"></div>

     <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="login" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-remote="login.html" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-xxlg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content loginContainer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

login.html

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <div class="row">
        <h4 class="modal-title " id="myModalLabel">User Login</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <section class="login-container row">
        <div class="login col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="boxed">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="agent">
                        <form role="form">
                             <div class="form-group float-label-control col-sm-4 ">
                               <label for="">Maximum Count</label>
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Maximum Count">
                             </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpane2" class="tab-pane" id="customer">
                                            <p>weterter</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
</div>
```

using floating label ref [link](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/float-label-pattern-forms)

Comment: Please explain `jquery is not working in remote Modal`. Any errors in console?

Comment: included jquery in index.htm, if include model inline working fine but remote not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing 2 things. Your input must have the `empty` class and your `label` must be after the `input`:

```html
<div class="modal-header">
    <div class="row">
        <h4 class="modal-title " id="myModalLabel">User Login</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <section class="login-container row">
        <div class="login col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="boxed">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="agent">
                        <form role="form">
                             <div class="form-group float-label-control col-sm-4 ">
                               <input type="text" class="form-control empty" placeholder="Maximum Count">
                               <label for="">Maximum Count</label>
                             </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpane2" class="tab-pane" id="customer">
                                            <p>weterter</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
</div>
```

Comment: include BS in your snippet